# Backbone.js. Make change event correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm writing Todo app with Backbone.js

You can see part of my code below.
Model:

```
 var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        title: 'Task Title',
        complete: false
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.on("change:complete", function () {
            alert("foo");
        });
    }
});
```

View:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        collection: todoCollection,
        el: 'body',
        events: {
            'click #tasks li .complete-task' : 'toggleComplete'
        }
        toggleComplete: function (e) {
            var modelCid = $(e.target).parent('li').attr('id');

             if ( this.collection.get(modelCid)['complete'] ){
                this.collection.get(modelCid)['complete'] = false;
             } else {
                 this.collection.get(modelCid)['complete'] = true;
             };
        }
    });
```

But something working wrong and change event in the model doesn't working. I can't understand where I have mistakes.
Help me, please.
10q.

Comment: I think it should be `this.on('change'` unless you are firing it manually. Not `change:complete`

Comment: `this.on('change'` doesn't work too

Comment: Ah, I think for the change event to be fired you need to use the `set` method on the model.

Comment: BTW. `if (condition) { something(false); } else { something(true); }` is an antipattern. Don't do that. Use `something( !condition );`, that's shorter and clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Backbone [Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set):

**Set** `model.set(attributes, [options])`

> Set a hash of attributes (one or
>   many) on the model. If any of the attributes change the model's state,
>   a "change" event will be triggered on the model. Change events for
>   specific attributes are also triggered, and you can bind to those as
>   well, for example: change:title, and change:content. You may also pass
>   individual keys and values.

So you need to be using the `set` method on the model for these events to be fired. So you would need to use something like this:

```
this.collection.get(modelCid).set('complete',false);
```